# Sequelize Get All Record from Current Month

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm currently working on an API to get all data from the current month using Sequelize as an ORM. Is there any way or documentation that I can refer to? I was using the Sequelize Op function but didn't get any data that I wanted. Are there any other ways to get the data using Sequelize ORM?

Answer (score 0):

I think the challenge here would be to get the first moment of the current month to use that on the query, something like this should work:

```
import { Op } from 'sequelize'

model.findAll({
  where: {
    createdAt: {
      [Op.gte]: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 1);    
    }
  }
})
```